# Binding two data frames with different names of columns and rows

Tags: r, data-analysis

R useRs,
I have two different data frames. I want to insert (e.t., rbind) the second data frame (df_2) after the last state name of each state. Here is a fake example of the two data frames:

```
states = rep(c("AL", "NE", "AR", "MO", "WA"),times = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10))
schools = randomNames::randomNames(50) ## 5 first last names separated by a space
Gender = rep(c("male", "female"),times = c(18,32))
type = rep(c("private", "public"),times = c(20,30))
item1 = rnorm(50, mean=25, sd=5)
item2 = rnorm(50, mean=30, sd=5)
item3 = rnorm(50, mean=15, sd=5)
df_1 = data.frame(states, schools, Gender, type, item1, item2, item3)

FirstQuestionOptions = c("Yes", "No")
SeconsQuestionOptions = c("one", "two")
ThirdQuestionOptions = c(88, 90)
df_2 = data.frame(FirstQuestionOptions, SeconsQuestionOptions, ThirdQuestionOptions)


df_3 should be the combination of df_1 and df_2.
```

Then, want to export each state data in a separate excel file using the following:

```
list_data <- split(df_3, df_3$states)
Map(openxlsx::write.xlsx, list_data, paste0(names(list_data), '.xlsx'))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `df_3` in the example.  use `dplyr::bind_rows(df_1, df_2)` to bind dataset having different names

Comment: It should be the combination of df_1 and df_2. Thanks for the question.

Comment: Did you meant `rbind` instead of `cbind`.  The `bind_rows` would help if it is rbind

Comment: Yes , Thanks, @akrun

Comment: No, it did not, just thanking you for the note :)

Comment: Why not write the state data first to the xlsx, and then add the df_2 to each? If you are  adding df_2 to the bottom of the whole dataset then it cannot be subsetted as part of your split command to appear on each state's file.

Comment: Hi @Jonni, I assume that adding the df_2 to each would take much time, especially there is so many states each week to analyze. Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: you would just write it iteratively to be added to the worksheet for each state. It would not take hardly any time at all

Comment: Would you be able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I am:

1. Looping through each unique state name in your dataset
2. Creating a new workbook each time
3. Adding a worksheet to that workbook that is the name of the state
4. Filtering df_1 down to just the state of interest's data
5. Adding the state's data to the worksheet
6. Then writing df_2 to each -- I just arbitrarily chose column J (i.e., the 10th column) but you can write that anywhere you want.

You can also specify if columns should be certain width with the style commands in openxlsx.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse) #probably don't need this whole library but I usually just have this loaded
for(i in unique(states)){

    wb<- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = i)
df_i = df_1 %>% 
    filter(states == i)
writeData(wb, sheet = i, x = df_i, startCol = 5)
writeData(wb, sheet = i, df_2, startCol = 1)
saveWorkbook(wb, paste0('YOURPATHWAY',i,".xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)

}
```

Comment: This is great, @Jonni. I changed the argument 'startCol' to 'startRow', btw. The only step I think I still need is to add 'df_2' by the beginning of the excel file so the rows do not get overlapped. The data set I've includes many rows so it's almost impossible to specify 'startRow = 10' or other number. thanks much again.

Comment: If you want the df_2 to start at beginning then have startCol = 1, and add a startCol = 5 (or more) for the df_i. if answer is satisfactory then please accept :-)